# How to share entities between domain services in WCF RIA Services framework?

Tags: .net, wcf, silverlight, rich-internet-application

If I would build a big WCF RIA Services application with multiple domain services how could I have certain entities, which are shared between those domain services and exposed by them in different context. For example I could have a Cutomer entity, which is exposed both by Orders and Loyalty modules/domain services. At least my own experiments with [ExternalAttribute] and others seem to indicate that this is not supported by the framework very well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you seen this tutorial by Microsoft?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff422034(VS.91).aspx